# How do I extract ints from a file using ReadLine() in Python?

Tags: python, readline

I have a file that is a list followed by several numbers (eg. Name 10 20 30). 
I need to extract the numbers from each line and use them to calculate the average of those numbers and reprint the names, followed by the averages, line by line. How do I extract the numbers from the line and use them in calculations in Python?

Comment: use regex, and please ask one question ,and post what you tried out

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file that looks like this:

```
list
list
list
list
90
43
54
67
12
45
```

you can extract the numbers using the `isdigit()` function and then add together each number together and count how many numbers it finds then divide the sum by the how many numbers it found.

```
info = file("info.txt").read()
info = info.split("\n")

avarage=0
count=0
for item in info:
    if item.isdigit():
        count=count+1
        avarage=avarage+int(item)

print avarage/count
```

The result is 51